# how to write a query that will return records within min and max date

Tags: sql, db2

I've a table that contains policynumber with effdte and expdte. policy term is one year and has records for every year. i'm trying to find if any claim was reported outside the policy period.

```
SELECT DISTINCT POLICY_NO,MIN(EFF_DATE) AS EFFDTE,MAX(EXP_DATE) AS EXPDTE 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY POLICY_NO;
```

I'm just not sure how do i combine that with Claimnumber that has a loss date within/not within that eff and exp date. 
Thanks

Comment: You rarely never combine GROUP BY and SELECT DISTINCT. Your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve too.

Comment: Are the Claim_Number and Loss_Date columns in the same table as Policy_No and EFF_DATE and EXP_DATE ?

Comment: Yeah same table

Comment: PolicyNum EffDte ExpDte ClaimNo LossDte
1234567890 20040125 20050125 4111731 20040804
1234567890 20040125 20050125 4112143 20040810
1234567890 20050125 20060125 5108639 20050615
1234567890 20060125 20070125 7100167 20070108
1234567890 20120125 20130125 12112386 20121001
1234567890 20160125 20170125 17101395 20170121
1234567890 20180125 20190125 18108257 20180515
1234567890 20180125 20190125 18108962 20180601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`SELECT c1.*
FROM CLAIMS c1
WHERE 
Lossdte < 
( select min(EffDte)
from claims c2
where c1.PolicyNum = c2.PolicyNum )
or
Lossdte > 
( select max(ExpDte)
from claims c2
where c1.PolicyNum = c2.PolicyNum )`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CLAIMS c
WHERE CLAIM_DATE < EFF_DATE OR CLAIM_DATE > EXP_DATE;
```

This returns all claims that are outside the eff/exp date for the policy.  According to your comments, all the data should be in the same row.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work. i need to find claims that is not within the life of that policy term. so my guess is i need to get the policy life by getting by using min and max then find the claimdate if it falls within the term.

Comment: PolicyNum EffDte ExpDte ClaimNo LossDte
1234567890 20040125 20050125 4111731 20040101
1234567890 20040125 20050125 4112143 20040810
1234567890 20050125 20060125 5108639 20050615
1234567890 20060125 20070125 7100167 20070108
1234567890 20120125 20130125 12112386 20121001
1234567890 20160125 20170125 17101395 20170129

Comment: say one of the claim Loss date less then eff date and other one is greater than the exp date, so i only need to find these two claims.